# Java and Scala integration with private modifiers

Tags: java, scala, bytecode, modifier

I've been defining private and protected methods from Scala classes, but when compiling to java bytecode, they just dissapear and all the methods become public! so when calling from java, I am able to call any of them. Is correct what I'm saying? and if so, wil this in the near future change with a new compiler?

Answer (score 2):

> I've been defining private and protected methods from Scala classes, but when compiling to java bytecode, they just dissapear and all the methods become public!

Scala's access modifier semantics don't map to the JVM's access modifier semantics. Any way to translate them must necessarily be an approximation. Sometimes, the closest possible approximation is `public`.

That's just the way it is. Just look at Scala-native for comparison, which compiles to native binary machine code: *all* access modifiers, and *all* types are *completely* gone, because there simply is no way to represent them in native binary machine code. Even Java can't be properly represented in JVM bytecode (e.g. Java has Generics, but the JVM has no way to represent them).

> so when calling from java, I am able to call any of them. Is correct what I'm saying?

Yes. When you use Java to interact with Scala code, you are circumventing any checking the Scala compiler does. There is no way around that.

> and if so, wil this in the near future change with a new compiler?

No. It would require a change in the JVM Specification to allow languages to specify their own access modifier semantics. I don't see that happening.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Here is an example of what I was talking about:




    class Person() {
    private def run() {
    }
    protected def walk(miles:Int){
    }
    }






In this case both methods (walk and run) become public ones, when using the class compiled (.class) from Java or Scala. I understand that the same happen  with generics, they are not a feature part of the virtual machine, but personally I see that modifiers are more important than generics, without generics, you can even do it the old way

Comment: Even Java’s `private` modifier on classes (relevant to nested types only) isn’t actually stored in the usual access modifier field. It’s stored in a special attribute dedicated to inner classes, supported by Reflection, whereas the JVM itself doesn’t enforce that `private` access level…

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes access is widened without any name mangling or obfuscation.

Here, you might expect the implementation to show default package access:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

package p { class C { private[p] def c = 42 }}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.


scala> :javap p.C
[snip]
  public int c();
```

A special accessor is provided here for pattern matching:

```
scala> case class C(private val c: Int)
defined class C

scala> :javap -pv C
[snip]
  private final int c;
    descriptor: I
    flags: ACC_PRIVATE, ACC_FINAL

  public int c$access$0();
```

It is not a good idea to rely on any such implementation detail for purposes of general interop. However, Scala promises binary compatibility within a release series such as 2.12.x. Anything compiled with 2.12.1 must link with new code compiled with 2.12.2.